# Carga muy lenta con datatable Jquery en mi proyecto laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, ajax, laravel-5, datatables

Tengo el problema que mi tabla al cargar datos por ejemplo 11,000 datos se traba o se pasma por un momento lo hace muy lento.

Este es como ejecuto DataTable, realmente son mas columnas pero he quitado algunas.

```
var genealogytable = $('#genealogy').DataTable({
    destroy: true,
    ajax: { 
       url: "reloadTab/"+idsponsor+"/"+period+"/"+typee,
       type: "GET", 
       datatype: "json" 
     },
    columns: [ 
        {
            data: null,
            className: "center",
            defaultContent: '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="addRowGen(this.parentNode.parentNode.id)">' + 
                '<img src="{{ asset('img/add2.png')}}" width="30px"/>' + 
            '</a>'
        },

        {
            'targets': 0,
            'searchable':false,
            'orderable':false,
            'className': 'dt-body-center',
            'render': function (data, type, row){
                return '<td> <p><label> <input type="checkbox" id="emailGenealog[]" name="email[]" class="check_mailGenealogy" onclick="mailRowGen(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id)" name="" value="'+row.email+'" /><span></span></label></p> </td>';
            }
        },
        {data: 'Line'},
        {data: 'Level'},
        {data: 'associateid'},
        {data: 'associatename'},

});
```

Y este es el  controlador donde corro un  Store Procedure para optener los datos,

```
    public function reloadTab(Request $request, $idsponsor, $period, $typee){
    $idsponsor = $request->idsponsor;
    $period = $request->period;
    $type = $request->typee;

    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
    $conection = \DB::connection('sqlsrvgenealogy');
        $response = $conection->select('EXEC Sp_TreePerId ?,?,?', array($idsponsor, $period, $type));
    \DB::disconnect('sqlsrvgenealogy');
    $data = [
        'data' => $response,
    ];
    return \Response::json($data);

}
```

y por ultimo la ruta

```
Route::get('reloadTab/{idsponsor}/{period}/{typee}', 'Genealogy\genealogyController@reloadTab');
```

Comment: Estas mandando los 11000 datos en una sola consulta a la vista?

Comment: @OmarRamirez si, ya que es un Store Procedure. No utilizo serverSide, ya que cuando lo pongo me pone todos los datos en una pagina  en otras palabras no me funciona la paginación

Comment: all tienes el problema entonces la idea es que los datos los uses desde el server side.. el front no aguanta tal canditdad de datos por eso se pone lento

Comment: @OmarRamirez entonces lo  que me estas diciendo  que no  puedo  hacer nada para lograr que funcione, o a que te refieres?

Comment: la unica manera es que uses del lado del servidor  y vayas enviando datos. si no , siempre cargara lento

Comment: ¿es lenta la respuesta o el DataTable en JS?
Si es el JS mira la ayuda del DataTable: https://datatables.net/faqs/#speed tiene algunos consejos.

Comment: Yo he de suponer que es la respuesta, por que con datos de 1000 si lo carga rapido